# Can't authenticate using email and password

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm trying to authenticate a user with a custom login form. I designed the form, and I'm trying to authenticate users like this:

```
Template['account.login'].events
'submit #login-form': (e, t) ->
e.preventDefault()

Meteor.loginWithPassword(
  t.find('#login_username').value,
  t.find('#login_password').value,
  (err)->
    console.log(err)
)
return false
```

Relevant Template(in JADE - sorry):

```
form.smart-form.client-form#login-form(novalidate)
    fieldset
        section
            label.input
                input#login_username(type="text", name="username")
        section
            label.input
                input#login_password(type="password", name="password")
    footer
        button.btn.btn-primary(type="submit", id="login.btn.login") Login
```

From the resource I found online, this would be correct. However, I get this exception thrown on the server:

```
Exception while invoking method 'login' Error: Match error: Failed Match.Where validation in field username in field user.username
```

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the template. Try to `console.log` the values before the call to `loginWithPassword` - probably one of them is empty.

Comment: ok, thanks, I updated the question to include the template code. I have outputted values in the console, and it seems they are picked up correctly. Could it have anything to do with and implicit check() method called on the arguments?

Comment: @Genu, how did you solve it? I'm in the same situation

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add a tab and `Meteor.loginWithPassword()` is running outside the Template event. Paste your coffeescript code at http://js2.coffee/ and you'll see it right away.